# Python - Using gspread to create a spreadsheet in a specific folder in Google Drive

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm trying to create a new spreadsheet using gspread, and I want to be able to control where it ends up.

```
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    sheetname = 'Test sheet'
    sheet = gc.create(sheetname)
```

I think that what's happening is that when I do gc.create(sheetname), it's making it in my Google service account, but I want it to end up in a specific folder in my normal account.

-

--Figured it out--

Needed to change to the following:

```
if parent_folder_ids:
    body["parents"] = parent_folder_ids
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may refer with this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/miohtama/f988a5a83a301dd27469).

```
def create_google_spreadsheet(title: str, parent_folder_ids: list=None, share_domains: list=None) -> Spreadsheet:
    """Create a new spreadsheet and open gspread object for it.
```

Be noted that created spreadsheet is not instantly visible in your Drive search and you need to access it by direct link.

Comment: How do you think I might go about making it be visible in Drive (in the folder I want it in)?