# How to upload CSV's to folder in Google Drive using Python

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets, google-drive-api, export

I have this little script made with help from @metamorporpoise which moves all of my CSVs from my folder on Mac to my Google Drive main directory. I am new to google API and even python so could someone give me a hint about what needs to be done to upload all of those CSV files to specified folder in Google Drive, and not to the main directory as this script does?

```
import gspread
import os
gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename='/users/krzysztofpaszta/credentials.json')

os.chdir('/users/krzysztofpaszta/CSVtoGD')

files = os.listdir()

for filename in files:
   if filename.split(".")[1] == "csv":
      sh = gc.create(filename.split(".")[0]+' TTF')
      content = open(filename, 'r').read().encode('utf-8') 
      gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: I'd check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606718/creating-a-spreadsheet-in-a-folder-with-gspread

Comment: If you want to achieve your goal using gspread, I think that this is the answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71698954 So, please modify `sh = gc.create(filename.split(".")[0]+' TTF')` to `sh = gc.create(filename.split(".")[0]+' TTF', folder_id="###folderId###")`. If this modification didn't work, please update gspread and test it again.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you, I figured it out in the same moment :p

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, I flagged as a duplicated question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to place it in a folder in your google drive instead of at the root. By what I can see, the `gc.create` function creates and empty sheet, after which `gc.import_csv` imports data into the sheet. So you only need to change the location where the create function runs. Similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44394992/3730626), and I will repeat the answer. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/miohtama/f988a5a83a301dd27469) has several functions related to the gspread package, and you should take a look at the `create_google_spreadsheet` function, which creates the sheet under a parent folder. You need to have:

> :param parent_folder_ids: A list of strings of parent folder ids (if any).

after which you can use:

```
body["parents"] = [
{
    'kind': 'drive#fileLink',
    'id': parent_folder_ids
}]
```

to set the parent folder where you want the file to be created.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add one line of code. I am learning, what can I say :p :

```
folder_id = '19vrbvaeDqWcxFGwPV82APWYTmBMEn-hi'
sh = gc.create(filename.split(".")[0]+' TTF', folder_id)
```

```
import gspread
import os
gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename='/users/krzysztofpaszta/credentials.json')

os.chdir('/users/krzysztofpaszta/CSVtoGD')

files = os.listdir()

for filename in files:
   if filename.split(".")[1] == "csv":
      folder_id = '19vrbvaeDqWcxFGwPV82APWYTmBMEn-hi'
      sh = gc.create(filename.split(".")[0]+' TTF', folder_id)
      content = open(filename, 'r').read().encode('utf-8') 
      gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)
```